# Local variable as an argument to function call

Tags: c++

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

string func() {

    string abc = "some string";
    return abc;

}

string func1(string s) {

    cout << "I got this: " << s << endl;

} 

int main() {

    func1(func());
}
```

This gives:

```
$ ./a.out 
I got this: some string
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The seg fault happens b/c I am trying to access parameter `s` that has not been initialized properly. This is b/c `abc` went out of scope and got destroyed after call to `func()` completed. **Is this understanding correct ?**

Comment: I made a mistake while asking this. I was supposed to have replaced the `string` return type in `func1` with `void`. Now I can't delete this question, so I will let it be and ask another question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem in `func1()`. It's defined to return a `std::string` but there is no `return` statement anywhere in the function. That is undefined behavior and the probable cause of the segfault. Fix that and the rest of the code should work okay.

Comment: Lets say I fixed `func1` to return a `void`. Why should I be allowed to access `s` in `func1`? I say this b/c as soon as `func` returns `abc` goes out of scope and gets destroyed...no ?

Comment: @abc `func()` returns a `std::string` **by value**, think of it as a copy. There is no lifetime problem. It would be an issue if you returned the string **by reference** that would dangle after the local was destroyed. You code is okay.

Answer (score 1):

No, your understanding is wrong.

`abc` went out of scope, but that's not a problem since you're returning a copy of it.

Look here:

```
string func1(string s) {
    cout << "I got this: " << s << endl;
}
```

You say the function is going to return a `string` but you don't return anything.
The problem occurs when the program tries to destroy the string you didn't return, because destroying something that doesn't exist is very problematic.

A reasonable compiler should warn you about this.

You need to either return a string, or declare the return value `void`.

Answer (score 1):

func1 is supposed to return a `string` -- an object associated with a destructor,
but you're failing to return one.
(compile with `-Wall` to get a warning about that).

Consequently when the destructor for the string (NOT) returned by `func1` gets called
at the end of `main` scope, it'll be working with a string object whose memory is garbage
and that'll most likely result in a segfault.

Indeed, if you compile the program with g++ on linux and run it under `gdb` you'll
get a segfault occuring in a call to free -- which is presumably, std::string's destructor
trying to free an invalid object.